Error to install anchor-bankrun
I am currently participating in the Solana Bootcamp, working on the Voting App project exercises as outlined in the following resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amAq-WHAFs8&t=5255s
However, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to install the anchor-bankrun (npm install anchor-bankrun) and returns the following error:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: template-next-tailwind-counter@0.1.0
npm error Found: @solana/web3.js@1.95.3
npm error node_modules/@solana/web3.js
npm error   @solana/web3.js@"^1.95.3" from the root project
npm error   @solana/web3.js@"^1.68.0" from @coral-xyz/anchor@0.30.1
npm error   node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor
npm error     @coral-xyz/anchor@"^0.30.1" from the root project
npm error     peer @coral-xyz/anchor@"^0.30.0" from anchor-bankrun@0.4.1
npm error     node_modules/anchor-bankrun
npm error       anchor-bankrun@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @solana/web3.js@">=1.78.4 <1.92.0" from anchor-bankrun@0.4.1
npm error node_modules/anchor-bankrun
npm error   anchor-bankrun@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution

Could you please advise on how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Do you have a link to your code?

It looks like there's a dependency issue with @solana/web3.js.
anchor-bankrun requires >=1.78.4 <1.92.0" while your project has 1.95.3. Recommend trying to downgrade your project for @solana/web3.jsto1.92.0`.
You can do this with:
npm i @solana/web3.js@1.92.0

